# Is Google Analytics Users metric equivalent to Webtrends Analytics Visitors metric?

Tags: session, google-analytics, metrics, visitors, webtrends

I hope there are some `Webtrends Analytics` experts on SO who can answer this question.

Once upon a time, `Google Analytics` had a *Unique Visitors* metric. Maybe around the year 2013 or 2014, *Unique Visitors* became *Users*. And *Visits* became *Sessions*.

In Webtrends Analytics, they define the terms *Visits*, *Visitors*, and *Unique Visitors* (see https://producthelp.webtrends.com/explore/glossary/ for more information). However, in their Visitors Dashboard, under Visitor Summary, they use the term `Visitors`. I cannot find any `dashboards` or `reports` which employ the term `Unique Visitors`. With that being said, how do I interpret the `Visitor` value in the Visitors Dashboard? Is it the number of unique visitors in a given time period? If the answer is yes, then it's equivalent to the Google Analytics `Users` metric.

Also for Webtrends Analytics, can the number of visitors be inflated if the only means of distinguishing a visitor is the client IP address + browser user agent string pair?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided is a glossary, like a dictionary for their site. It is not a definition of the metrics that's in webtrends. For your purpose, Unique visitors and visitors are the same. It is the equivalent of users in GA (basic installation, with [user-id enabled](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en), GA does session unification)

In webtrends, the detection is based on cookie, so yes, it can be inflated.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Yes, in a GA install, I do have user-id enabled (which is the default, iirc). I was going to create a separate SO question for a follow up but here it goes: In Webtrends, unique visitor method is set to client IP + user agent. A built-in Webtrends tool imports an IIS web log file to calculate metrics. My question is how can Webtrends possibly distinguish a new visitor from a returned visitor without the cookie method? I don't think it can, not without some other parameter. Do you agree? And couldn't that cause all visitors to basically be new visitors?

Comment: That depends on what's in the IIS logs and what webtrends is doing with the logs. There could be session ids or other information/logic used to determine unique visitors, looks like you're talking about on premis webtrends, if it is really only using IP and user agent then I agree it isn't a very good way of tracking.

Comment: Great feedback. I can tell you in the iIS logs there are no session ids. No cookies. Standard IIS Web logs. Only added parameter is X-Forwarded-For IP. I couldn't tell you what Webtrends is doing with the logs, and I am talking about on-prem Webtrends, yes. (version 9).

Comment: And definitely not an optimum way of tracking. I don't see how, without at least one or more parameters Webtrends can identify a return visitor from a new visitor. I can tell you the number of users in Webtrends versus GA in a month's time is more than 3 times. The numbers are way off and that includes Visits vs Sessions. If I knew precisely how Webtrends' code digests the web log files, it'd be much easier to isolate the factors as to why the gap between both systems are so far apart. Thanks again for your help.